# Maple - LinearSolve evaluates seemingly equivalent augmented matrix differently

Tags: maple

I am trying to get myself acquainted with Maple and was fooling around with some linear algebra.

I noticed that the following commands

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra);

P:=<0.6,0.3;0.4,0.7>;
Id := IdentityMatrix(2);

A:=P-Id;
b:=ZeroVector(2);

Aug1:=<A|b>;
LinearSolve(Aug1,free='x');
```

produce the unexpected result
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0. \\
-0. \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Entering the augmented matrix manually, however

```
Aug2:=<-0.4,0.3,0;0.4,-0.3,0>;
LinearSolve(Aug2,free='x');
```

does produce the result I was expecting
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.750000000000000x_1 \\
x_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The only difference I see, is that **Aug1** looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.400000000000000 & 0.300000000000000 & 0 \\
0.400000000000000 & -0.300000000000000 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
while **Aug2** looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.4 & 0.3 & 0 \\
0.4 & -0.3 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Using *whattype()* I already determined that both **Aug1** and **Aug2** have the **Matrix** datatype and their elements have the **float** datatype.

Any idea how I could produce the expected result using **Aug1** ($=P-Id$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add your Matrix `A` (whose entries are all of type `numeric`, and at least one is a float) to your `Id` the 2x2 identity Matrix, then the result has `datatype=float[8]` and is stored in so-called *hardware double precision*.

That is a base-2 format, in which the floats 0.3 and 0.7 cannot be represented exactly. Notice how the following values `p1` and `temp` differ by a very small (but nonzero!) amount. I use Maple's `evalhf` mode here, to mimic the double precision operations in question.

```
evalhf(proc() local p1,p2,res,temp;
   p1:=0.3; p2:=0.7;
   temp:=p2-1.0; res:=p1+temp;
   eval(lprint([p1,temp,res]));
   return NULL; end proc()):

   [.299999999999999989, -.300000000000000044,
     -.555111512312578270e-16]

HFloat(0.3), HFloat(0.7)-HFloat(1.0):
lprint(%);

  HFloat(.299999999999999989), 
  HFloat(-.300000000000000044)

`+`(%);

                        -17
    -5.55111512312578 10
```

Notice the `res` is not exactly `0.0`.

At the default values for the environment variables `Digits` (10) and `UsehardwareFloats` (`deduced`) the following `LinearAlgebra` computations are done in hardware double precision.

The result from `LinearSolve` is indeed a single, valid solution, but the parametric answer is not obtained. That is because the linear-solving algorithm does not detect that the two rows are "close enough" to being merely elementwise negations of each other.

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):
P:=<0.6,0.3;0.4,0.7>:
Id := IdentityMatrix(2):
b:=ZeroVector(2):

UseHardwareFloats; # default is `deduced`

             deduced

A:=P-Id;

       [-0.400000000000000   0.300000000000000]
  A := [                                      ]
       [ 0.400000000000000  -0.300000000000000]

lprint(A);

  Matrix(2,2,{(1, 1) =
  HFloat(-.400000000000000022),
  (1, 2) = HFloat(.299999999999999989),
  (2, 1) = HFloat(.400000000000000022),
  (2, 2) = HFloat(-.300000000000000044)}, 
  datatype = float[8],storage = rectangular,
  order = Fortran_order,shape = [])

Aug1:=<A|b>:

LinearSolve(Aug1);

              [-0.]
              [   ]
              [-0.]
```

The following provides some insight as to how that was computed.

```
LUDecomposition(Aug1);

  [1  0]  [1.0   0.]  [-0.400000000000000        0.300000000000000  0.]
  [    ]  [        ]  [                                               ]
  [0  1], [-1.  1.0], [                                        -17    ]
                    [                0.  -5.55111512312578 10     0.]

RowOperation(Aug1,[2,1],1);

     [-0.400000000000000        0.300000000000000  0]
     [                                              ]
     [                                        -17   ]
     [                0.  -5.55111512312578 10     0]

ReducedRowEchelonForm(Aug1);

          [ 1.  -0.  -0.]
          [             ]
          [-0.   1.  -0.]
```

Notice the similarity with the earlier scalar computation. Notice that the bottom row of the results from `ReducedRowEchelonForm` and `RowOperation` are not all zero, and neither is the `L` Matrix returned by `LUDecomposition`.

One way to work around this issue is to perform the computations in so-called "software floats", which in Maple means a base-10 floating-point format in which the values 0.3 and 0.7 can be stored "exactly".

```
SFloat(0.3), SFloat(0.7)-SFloat(1.0):
lprint(%);

  .3, -.3

`+`(%);

            0.
```

With the default value of `deduced` for `UseHardwareFloats` then software floats will get used if `Digits` is greater than 15. Or `UseHardwareFloats` could be set to `false` and then software floats would get used, for any valid setting of `Digits`.

Let's re-do all those computations, with `UseHardwareFloats` set to `false`.

```
UseHardwareFloats:=false:

A:=P-Id;

           [-0.4   0.3]
      A := [          ]
           [ 0.4  -0.3]

lprint(A);

  Matrix(2,2,{(1, 1) = -.4, (1, 2) = .3,
  (2, 1) = .4, (2, 2) = -.3},
  datatype = sfloat,storage = rectangular,
  order = Fortran_order,shape = [])

Aug1:=<A|b>:

LinearSolve(Aug1);

         [0.7500000000 _t0[1]]
         [                   ]
         [      _t0[1]       ]
```

The following provides some insight as to how that was computed.

```
LUDecomposition(Aug1);

     [1  0]  [          1.  0.]  [-0.4  0.3  0.]
     [    ], [                ], [             ]
     [0  1]  [-1.000000000  1.]  [  0.   0.  0.]

RowOperation(Aug1,[2,1],1);

         [-0.4  0.3  0]
         [            ]
         [  0.   0.  0]

ReducedRowEchelonForm(Aug1);

     [1.  -0.7500000000  -0.]
     [                      ]
     [0.             0.   0.]
```

Another way to get at a parametric solution for your example is to compute the `NullSpace` (Kernel) of your `A` Matrix, and form a parametrized linear combination of the (here, one) Vector in the basis.

This question is about Maple programming and not about mathematics per se, and as such is off-topic in this forum.  More suitable would be [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) or [www.mapleprimes.com](https://www.mapleprimes.com) the Maplesoft user forum.